# Drawing line from variable number of points stored in two lists

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, latitude-longitude, list

I have two Python list `latitude` and `longitude` which stores the coordinates, and I want to draw a single line from the list coordinates.

I can draw the line if I know the number of latitude/longitude.

```py
# suppose the line is having 2 longitudes and 2 latitudes.
QgsFeature().setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(78.3022187,23.7875547),QgsPointXY(98.3022187,33.7875547)]))

# suppose the line is having 3 longitudes and 3 latitudes.
QgsFeature().setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(78.3022187,23.7875547),QgsPointXY(98.3022187,33.7875547),QgsPointXY(148.3022187,133.7875547)]))
```

How can I draw a line in QGIS through Python, for the variable number of points?

Comment: You have already drawn a line from variable number of points. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: we have two python list 'latitude' and 'longitude' which stores the co-ordinates, and i want to draw a single line from the list co-ordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, Python [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function comes into play.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()

longitudes = [5, 10, 15, 20]
latitudes = [5, 10, 5, 10]

### zip function in list comprehension
coords = [QgsPointXY(lon, lat) for lon, lat in zip(longitudes, latitudes)]
###

feature = QgsFeature()
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(coords)
feature.setGeometry(line)

layer.addFeature(feature)
layer.commitChanges()
```

[image]